# Different width between AutoCompleteTextView and suggestions

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` item in my app `layout`. I'd like to reserve just a tiny space for it in the `layout`, so the user can touch it and begin to write. Instead, I'd like that the list with suggested words that pops up is wider, for example like the entire screen. Actually, the pop-up words list is as wide as the `textView`.

Comment: what you have tried so far...

Comment: I've found solution. See my answer. Thank you anyway Ram.

Answer (score 4):

I've found a simple solution. Attribute `android:dropDownWidth`. For example, I can set `android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"`. Excuse me for posting a question and then founding the answer immediately after.